# Implementing PayPal in Java/Spring based application

Tags: java, spring, paypal

I need to implement PayPal in Java/Spring/Spring-MVC based application.

It is quite hard to find any good tutorial on this issue. Is there any good information around that could help me, or show me a good direction?

Do you have any experience doing this? Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two paypal plugins, actually.

Peter Delahunty wrote the paypal pro plugin but there is also the simpler Paypal plugin that just adds the Paypal Button.

On top of this, there is also another solution by paypal called Paypal Website Payment Pro, which is a hosted solution that doesn't require you to use all the PCI compliance stuff that the Paypal plugin requires. The tricky bit with this one is handling transactions and the IPN that gets sent by Paypal.

Do you know which solution you are using from Paypal?

Answer (score 1):

There is a grails plugin which may do what your looking for http://www.grails.org/plugin/paypal-pro. Sourced from similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975313/how-should-we-integrate-paypal-adaptive-and-ipn-api-in-a-java-webserver-enviro)

Answer (score 1):

This little project is made for encapsulating Paylpal NVP calls:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/paypal-nvp/
Scarce documentation, but code is clear.

This tutorial has a messier code but it's explained:
http://finker.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/paypal-adaptive-api-and-spring-3-rest-template-part-1/